# Making a variable equal to a list of strings in python

Tags: python, pycharm, read.csv

I am working on a program that parses stock data from several websites. The websites I use for each stock are the same and luckily most of them are pretty easy to generate URLs for.

EX: Yahoo's stock summary page URL is "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ticker+"?p="+ticker 
where all I need to do is prompt the user to enter the company ticker and I can easily generate a useable URL to parse with BeautifulSoup

```
    ticker = input("Enter Company Ticker:")
    ticker = ticker.strip()
    URLyahooSum = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ticker+"?p="+ticker
    print(URLyahooSum)

    >>> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CBG?p=CBG
```

This part was easy and I can run the program to parse the data for individual tickers inputed by the user, however, now I'm trying to set the ticker variable to be equal to a basket of tickers that will run the program on each individual ticker in the basket and save all of the outputs as different .csv files that I can put in a SQL database where I can constantly rank the basket of companies from best to worst.

I'm trying to conquer one aspect at a time so for right now I'm just concerned about how to tell the program to set the "ticker" variable to each ticker in the basket individually and to run until it has reached the last ticker.

I already have the basket of company tickers I want in the database in a .csv file so how can I tell the program that I want "ticker" to equal each one of those companies. and to run the program for each ticker.

Comment: what do you mean by "*now I'm trying to set the ticker variable to be equal to a basket of tickers*" ?

Comment: I mean that I want the program to run on each ticker in the basket. For example I would like the Program to run on company 'a' , output the results and then run on company 'b' (with 'a' and 'b' being in the basket). The basket I have is of REITs and I am collecting their parsed data in csv files that I can pull up with a SQL program and essentially rank them.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you should read your data from CSV file instead of user input.

I will assume that you have a simple CSV file as below [named: a.csv];

```
company,ticker
CBRE Group,CBG
Advanced Micro Devices,AMD
The Boeing Company, BA
Eli Lilly and Company, LLY
Xerox Corporation, XRX
```

to recieve each ticker from the file, you would need the following code.

```
import csv
with open('a.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['ticker'].strip())
```

the result of the script

```
>>> CBG
>>> AMD
>>> BA
>>> LLY
>>> XRX
```

Since we can receive data from the file, here is the final version of the script:

```
import csv

with open('a.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        ticker = row['ticker'].strip()
        URLyahooSum = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ticker+"?p="+ticker
        print(URLyahooSum)
```

this would give you the following output:

```
>>> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CBG?p=CBG
>>> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD?p=AMD
>>> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA?p=BA
>>> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LLY?p=LLY
>>> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XRX?p=XRX
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the problem is how do I get the program to run on each ticker, one at a time.    Ex: runs on CBG and outputs results, then runs on AMD and outputs results, and so on. Will the program just no to do one at a time?

Comment: @michaelharris it’s the same logic. Instead of printing the url, you can write parsing function from the site and print them out or save to somewhere else. If you need anything else, I would like you to provide me more details, so I can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the tickers in a list `tickers_list`, you can do

```
for ticker in tickers_list:
    print("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ticker+"?p="+ticker)
```

This is called a for each loop, and the `ticker` variable will be taking the value of each item in the list throughout the loop's iterations.
So if `tickers_list = ['ABC', 'BBC', 'CBC']`, this would make `ticker` have the value of 'ABC' the first iteration, then 'BBC' the second, and 'CBC' the third.

This might be more useful for you I think since you probably have a function that will need a string already prepared to be worked with:

```
base_string = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s?p=%s"
for ticker in tickers_list:
    current_url = base_string % (ticker,ticker)
    my_function(current_url)
```

This is called string formatting, where you have a placeholder in the string and you fill it up later. Each `%s` in the `base_string` needs a variable to fill it, and that's why in making the `current_url` the percent sign is followed by two `ticker`s.

Comment: would that just be a simple list like:          ticker = [ABC, BBC, CBC, ...etc.]?

Comment: Exactly. A list of strings though: ['ABC', 'BBC', 'CBC', ...].